# Enforce override method to base class

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, partial-classes, overriding

I have the following  code:

```
public partial class Root : ICustomInterface
{
    public virtual void Display()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Root");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
public class Child : Root
{
    public override void Display()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Child");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Root temp;
        temp = new Root();
        temp.Display();
    }
}

Output: "Root"
Desired output: "Child"
```

When I instantiate a `Root` object and call the `Display()` method I want to display the overridden method in `Child` is this possible.

I need this because I must create a plugin that's an extension to the base code and voids the `Display()` method of the `Root` class and implements only the plugin's method `Child`

Comment: I don't think you fully understand inheritance. you need to create an instance of Child if you want the Display() method to output "Child"

Comment: For your edited part of question you should see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779146/c-is-there-way-for-a-class-to-remove-methods-that-it-has-inherited and also this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125746/how-to-hide-remove-a-base-classs-methods-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not possible you have to instantiate a Child object instead of a root

```
Root temp;
temp = new Child();
temp.Display();
```

if you don't want to modify temp then you have to modify Root display method to print "child" instead of root

Comment: I don't want to modify the temp object.

Comment: I don't want to do that I want to create a plugin and not modify the base code of the project, the plugin must be an extension that voids the Root method and calls only my Child method.

Comment: That's impossible, if the object is a Root and Root display "Root".
How are you gonna modify the output if you can't modify the code?

Answer (score 6):

> When I instantiate a Root object and call the Display() method I want
>   to display the overridden method in Child is this possible.

You need to create instance of the `Child` class.

```
Root temp;
temp = new Child(); //here
temp.Display();
```

Currently your object `temp` is holding reference of the base class, it doesn't know anything about the child, hence the output from the base class.

Answer (score 2):

> When I instantiate a Root object and call the Display() method I want to display the overridden method in Child is this possible.

No. Suppose you add another class:

```
public class Child2 : Root
{
    public override void Display()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Child 2");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Then which method (`Child.Display()` or `Child2.Display()`) would you expect to be called for a `Root` instance?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible with your current code because you are creating a `Root` instance and not a `Child` instance. Therefore it has no idea about the `Display` method inside `Child`.

You'll need to create a `Child` class:

```
Root temp;
temp = new Child();
temp.Display();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not how OOP works. You cannot use an overridden method in a base class. If you do this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Root temp;
    temp = new Child();
    temp.Display();
}
```

You should get your desired output.

Comment: I don't want to modify the temp object.

Comment: Then you don't know what you're doing